# pt-table-checksum does't work with multi source (mariadb) Edit

Tags: percona

pt-checksum is getting to never ending loop in multi-source (channel based) replication :

A multi source replication in my environment

> n1 -> n2 (created n1 as channel replication)
>     n2 -> n3
>     n1 -> n3 (n3 will replicate from both n1 and n2 channels)

Whenever without channel wise replication pt-checksum is working fine. (traditional replication/default replication works without any issues)

Once i enabled as channel wise(only n1, removed the n2 channel) replication (n1->n3) , the pt-checksum is not going through.

> Replica n3-VirtualBox is stopped. Waiting.
>         Replica n3-VirtualBox is stopped. Waiting.

from general log n1:

> Query    SELECT 'pt-table-checksum keepalive'
>              Query    SELECT 'pt-table-checksum keepalive'

Comment: Please open a bug report at https://jira.percona.com/ on this. There's a good chance that pt-table-checksum just simply does not work with multi-source yet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by following method:

On Master DB Server

(i) For safe side, I made copy of original /bin/pt-table-checksum

cp /bin/pt-table-checksum /bin/pt-table-checksumorg

(ii) Open the /bin/pt-table-checksum file

vi /bin/pt-table-checksum

(iii) Go to line number 8590
 Press esc, type 8590 , press shift g

(iv) replace the line
   my @lagged_slaves = map { {cxn=>$_, lag=>undef} } @$slaves;
by
    my @lagged_slaves = ();

the program immediately works and returns the expected results.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem. I also get infinite loop of "Replica dbslave is stopped." However if I break the output by pressing "Ctl + c", I get the inconsistent database and table name. I verified it and found the inconsistency in slave. Then I used pt